# How to get element index at PLinq ForAll

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, plinq

I have the following code:

```
line.Split(' ').AsParallel().ForAll(word =>
{
    // How to get element index?
}
```

How do I get the current element's index? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [overload of `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413608(v=vs.100).aspx) that lets you access the index.

```
line.Split(' ')
    .AsParallel()
    .Select((w, i) => new { Index = i, Word = w })
    .ForAll(x => ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use [`Parallel.Foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can provide indexes too.

```
Parallel.ForEach(line.Split(' '),(word,state,index) =>
{

});
```

Note that this is not plinq. it requires to import`System.Threading.Tasks`